# kendo editor ReferenceError: uid is not defined

Tags: editor, kendo-ui, referenceerror

I'm trying to create a image upload with the kendo editor.
I'm always getting an error:

> ReferenceError: uid is not defined
>
> ...==E&&(E=1),g?(b&&(A+=-b),w&&(I+=-w),e=new
>   Date(Date.UTC(F,D,E,A,I,H,N))):(e=new ...
>
> kendo.web.min.js (Zeile 11)

I'm using jQuery 1.8.3 and kendoui.web.2013.1.319.open-source

My code is as follow:

```
<div id="example" class="k-content">
    <textarea id="editor" rows="10" cols="30" name="reply-content"></textarea>
</div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#editor").kendoEditor({
                    imageBrowser: {
                        messages: {
                            dropFilesHere: "Drop files here"
                        },
                        transport: {
                            read: "/images/ImageBrowser/Read",
                            destroy: "/images/ImageBrowser/Destroy",

                            create: "/images/ImageBrowser/Create",

                            thumbnailUrl: "/images/ImageBrowser/Thumbnail",
                            uploadUrl: "/images/ImageBrowser/Upload",
                            imageUrl: "/images/ImageBrowser/Image?path={0}"
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Has someone experienced the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably returning a list of string, but the editor is waiting for an json result (name, type, size). You can check the demo with a sniffer to see what kind of results is expected from read/thumbnail, etc. Not very sure if you really must implement an server class for Kendo's client equivalent, but, by default, the result for Read is expected as Json for sure.

Comment: On the contrary, Read expects contentType of "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" by default, according to the [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/editor#configuration-imageBrowser.transport.read.contentType).

Answer (score 0):

New finaly i got it to work. I used some workarounds but see your self.

You can also test the functionality on the site:  http://jonas.dnsd.me/forum/topic?id=113

But stil it has some bugs like the url: /imageBrowser/?path=/image.jpg. I remove '/?path=' with a javascript function, but it works just for 3 images.
If you upload a image the window will not refreseh.

I would appreciate some ideas about the issues.

Now it is working like a charm ... see at http://jonas.dnsd.me/forum/topic?id=113
I updated to new source code